# Increment a field in runtime for Synapse SQL dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a task to increment the expected flag column by looking in to existing values.
I solved this using while loop and I can get the expected value updated  using while loop in Azure synapse-Sql Data warehouse.
But I would like to know a direct way to do this using any ranking functions?

My sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[work_table](
[work_order_key] [int] NULL,
[modification_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
[from_status] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[to_status] [varchar](100) NULL,
[count] [int] NULL,
[sequence] [int] NULL,
[count_VCR] [int] NULL,
[flag] [int] NULL,
[flag_expected] [int] NULL
  )

  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-14T11:53:05.1630000' AS DateTime2), N'Not Reviewed', N'Planned', 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-19T03:49:25.7370000' AS DateTime2), N'Planned', N'In Progress', 1, 2, 1, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-19T04:22:33.0630000' AS DateTime2), N'In Progress', N'Awaiting Parts', 1, 3, 1, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-27T02:58:54.7570000' AS DateTime2), N'Awaiting Parts', N'Parts Ordered', 1, 4, 0, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-27T02:59:00.8530000' AS DateTime2), N'Parts Ordered', N'Parts Received', 1, 5, 0, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-27T02:59:09.9000000' AS DateTime2), N'Parts Received', N'Planned', 1, 6, 0, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-28T07:59:58.1130000' AS DateTime2), N'Planned', N'In Progress', 1, 7, 1, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-04-29T07:53:30.9030000' AS DateTime2), N'In Progress', N'Work Completed', 1, 8, 1, 1, NULL)
  INSERT [dbo].[work_table] ([work_order_key], [modification_date], [from_status], [to_status], [count], [sequence], [count_VCR], [flag], [flag_expected]) VALUES (1002586, CAST(N'2022-05-05T06:15:34.4300000' AS DateTime2), N'Work Completed', N'Completed', 1, 9, 0, 1, NULL)
```

My expected result is
[image]

Partition column is [work_order_key] and any column from the list as the way it is suitable.
While loop can get this answer. I used work_order_key and count_VCR column to get this in a while loop. But I want to check with the group for direct query using the any SQL window or ranking functions.

I cannot add my solution as it is production one. This is sample data set only.
Thanks for the support.

Comment: "*Partition column is [work_order_key]*" - Cool, and the `ORDER BY` field(s) for the window function are? "*and any column from the list as the way it is suitable.*" - Huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.** There are many solutions, but a typical one is to use `LAG` and then a windowed `COUNT`.

```
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      PrevCount_VCR = LAG(wt.count_VCR) OVER (PARTITION BY wt.work_order_key ORDER BY wt.sequence)
    FROM dbo.work_table wt
)
SELECT *,
  New_flag_expected = COUNT(CASE WHEN wt.count_VCR = wt.PrevCount_VCR THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
    OVER (PARTITION BY wt.work_order_key ORDER BY wt.sequence ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM PrevValues wt;
```

And as an `UPDATE` statement (note there are no joins needed in SQL Server as you can update the CTE directly).

```
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      PrevCount_VCR = LAG(wt.count_VCR) OVER (PARTITION BY wt.work_order_key ORDER BY wt.sequence)
    FROM dbo.work_table wt
),
Counted AS (
    SELECT *,
      New_flag_expected = COUNT(CASE WHEN wt.count_VCR = wt.PrevCount_VCR THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY wt.work_order_key ORDER BY wt.sequence ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM PrevValues wt
)
UPDATE Counted
SET flag_expected = New_flag_expected;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/-YDylZwd)

Comment: RE: "you can update the CTE directly" - Are you sure in "Azure Synapse Analytics"? The "Syntax for Azure Synapse Analytics and Microsoft Fabric" doesn't indicate this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. This isn't a product that I use directly but from what I have seen in SO questions the supported TSQL surface area is fairly different from SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe not, I wasn't concentraing on that. So then it would need a self-join by primary key.